# Applicative Functor - Haskell

Tags: haskell, applicative

`pure (+)  <*> (Just 1) <*> (Just 2)`

Is the expansion of above expression is correct?

```
pure (+)  <*> (Just 1) <*> (Just 2)
= (Just (+)) <*> (Just 1) <*> (Just 2)
= (Just (1+)) <*> (Just 2)
= Just 3
```

if so then why we can't do just this `(Just (+)) <*> (Just 2)` ?

Comment: You can do just `(Just (+)) <*> (Just 2)` why do you think you can't? It's type is `Num a => Maybe (a -> a)` so you'll have to apply it to something else before you print it though. In fact for the `Applicative` instance of `Maybe` [`pure` is just another spelling of `Just`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1130)

Comment: No I was getting this error when I was trying to do it in the GHCI. So I thought my understanding of the partial application of the addition operator is not correct. 

<interactive>:8:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: Can you say what output you expected from ghci after entering `Just (+) <*> Just 2`? Perhaps it is merely your expectations that are mistaken, not the other things you wrote in this question.

Comment: No I thought I would back this "Just (2 +)". but now I understand to print the result I need to fully apply the function.

Comment: In GHCi `No instance for (Show T)` essentially means that the expression is fine, but there is no way to print the result. Functions can not be printed: there's no easy way to do that in general.

Comment: You will get a very similar error if you type `(2 +)` in GHCi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have already answered your question in the comments.  So just for the sake of completion...

`(Just (+)) <*> (Just 2)` is a partially applied function that the REPL cannot print, giving the error:

`• No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer)) arising from a use of ‘print’`,

but otherwise it is fine.

---

No problem here:

`> :t (Just (+)) <*> (Just 2)`

`(Just (+)) <*> (Just 2) :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)`.

---

Completing the function is fine too:

`> f = (Just (+)) <*> (Just 2)`

`> f <*> Just 1`

`> Just 3`

Your understanding seems perfectly sound.

---

Incidentally, another way of writing this is:

`(+) <$> (Just 1) <*> (Just 2)`

Answer (score 1):

The expansion is indeed **correct**. The expression

```
pure (+) <*> Just 1 <*> Just 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
(+) <$> Just 1 <*> Just 2
```

and:

```
liftA2 (+) (Just 1) (Just 2)
```

and not just for `Maybe`, but for any `Applicative` type.

A "mechanical" expansion would be to first look at the expression, here the expression

```
pure (+) <*>1 Just 1 <*>2 Just 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
(<*>2) ((<*>1) (pure (+)) (Just 1)) (Just 2)
```

where I added subscripts to keep track of the two uses of `<*>`. At this time we don't know what `Applicative` instance `pure` will "pick", but this will be determined based on the "*type propagation*".

The outer `(<*>)`, so `(<*>2)` has type `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, and for the inner one we pick `(<*>1) :: Applicative g => g (c -> d) -> g c -> g d`. The second operand of the two are `Num m => Maybe m` and `Num n => Maybe n`. This thus means that both `f` and `g` will match with `f ~ g ~ Maybe`.

This thus also means that `pure` will take the `Maybe` instance of `Applicative`, which means that `pure` is just equivalent to `Just`, and therefore `pure (+)` will - in this case - be `Num o => Just (o -> o -> o)`. If we match this with the type of the inner `(<*>)`, then it means that `o ~ m`, and with the outer `(<*>)`, it means that `o ~ m ~ n`. So the type of the expression will be:

```
pure (+) <*> Just 1 <*> Just 2 :: Num m => Maybe m
```

and as for the expansion, we can replace `pure` with `Just`, so:

```
Just (+) <*> Just 1 <*> Just 2
```

then `Just (+) <*> Just 1` will convert to `Just (1 +)` because both operands are a `Just`, and operand is implemented as:

> ```
> instance Applicative Maybe where
>     pure = Just
>
>     Just f  <*> m       = fmap f m
>     Nothing <*> _m      = Nothing
> ```

finally the `Just (1 +) <*> Just 2`, works the same, so:

```
Just (1 + 2)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Just 3
```

> if so then why we can't do just this `(Just (+)) <*> (Just 2)`.

We can, we only can't *`show`* the result. The result of `Just (+) <*> Just 2` will be `Just (2 +)`, so that is a function, and functions can not be shown (by default).

But we can for example do:

```
ghci> Just (1 +) <*> Just 2
Just 3
```

or we can use the result of `Just (+) <*> Just 2` to then work on a second operand:

```
ghci> (Just (+) <*> Just 2) <*> Just 3
Just 5
```

The parenthesis are not necessary here, but are used to makes it more explicit how the expression should be read.

Comment: Thank you, Actually I got little confused cause the function is embedded inside the Maybe data structure. So I thought it would get printed.

Comment: @RifatAhmed: well for `Just 2` it prints `Just 2`, so it basically prints `"Just "` followed by the `show` of the item wrapped in it, and then the problems start.

Comment: got it now, thanks